# How to install php7-mbstring in MAMP php 7.0.15

Tags: macos, mamp, php-7, macos-sierra, mbstring

How to install `mbstring` in Mac OS for PHP 7.0.15 is maintained by MAMP?

I tried to use `sudo port`, it does not work